# Where can I find Java FuelSdk Examples?

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

Where can I find a reasonably complete Java example for connecting to ExactTarget and updating a Data Extension.

It isn't in the documention. I've looked there already. ET just says its coming. Does anyone have simple examples they can share?

Answer (score 4):

These examples are available starting [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/java/getting-started-with-the-java-sdk.html). There are specific code snippets available for most common use cases.

- [Create Campaigns](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/campaigns/campaign-create.html) - Look under Java tab
- [Retrieve Campaigns](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/campaigns/campaign-retrieve.html) - Look under Java tab

This has Java code snippets available for all commonly used entities.

- Campaigns
- Campaign Assets
- Content Areas
- Data Extensions
- Data Extension Columns
- Data Extension Rows
- Emails
- Folders
- Lists
- List Subscribers
- Subscribers
- Triggered Sends
- Tracking
- Convenience Methods

Comment: Thanks, this is where I was looking. Very few of the Java tabs have code examples. Most say "Coming soon".

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the Fuel Java SDK test folder https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/tree/master/src/test/java/com/exacttarget/fuelsdk. Seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can looking on unit-test of Fuel-SDK. 
This should help you start.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java

Comment: Can you add some more information on this? Link only answers tend to break over time, and while that may not be the case with GitHub it does pay to include useful content.

Comment: The test classes are useless to show how to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking using Proxy with Fuel SDK then check out https://github.com/nidongara/FlamesSDK-Java

Comment: Please include a bit more than the link as an answer as link only answers are prone to links breaking.