# How to delete rows from DataExtension having no Primary Key, and exist in different Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

I refered [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/326525/74460) approach to delete rows from Data Extensions having no primary key. But this require to put SSJS script into every business unit. I tried with WSProxy by setting different clientId , but it doesn't not delete from Data Extensions which don't have primary key set.

How can I delete records from Data Extensions (having no Primary Key set) of other business units, without writing automation script in each Business Unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with Salesforce team, WSProxy do not provide same capabilities like Platform api to delete/update data of Data Extensions having no primary key.

Hence both WSProxy and Platform API have their own limitations as follows:-

1. WSProxy can impersonate to other BU, hence can retrieve, maninpulate data extensions of different BUs, just setting client ID of that BU while initializing WSProxy client. But it cannot manipulate records of Data Extensions which do not have any primary key.

Hence the only way is to copy-paste deletion/updation scipt into every Business Unit. However we can trigger these automation from one BU using WS Proxy.

2. Platform.Function api have capabilities to delete/update records of Data Extensions which do not have primary key, but it cannot impersionate different BU. Hence it can't access Data Extensions of other BU, except the current one.